# Support session cookies with Asyncio

Tags: cookies, python-3.x, python-asyncio, redirectwithcookies, aiohttp

I made a scraping script in Python which I need to use with Asyncio. I also need it to support web cookies. Originally made with urllib.request, the script looks like that:

```
urls = ['example.com/subdomain-A', 'example.com/subdomain-B', 'example.com/subdomain-C', ...]
for url in urls:
    page = bs4.BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.build_opener(req.HTTPCookieProcessor).open(url))
    # Do some stuff with page
```

This works fine for now, but I also need to make it multithreaded with Asyncio. Since I did not found any documentation about it, I tried the following:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def get(*args, **kwargs):
    response = yield from aiohttp.request('GET', *args, **kwargs)
    res = yield from response.read()
    return res
        
@asyncio.coroutine
def scraper(url):
    connector = aiohttp.connector.BaseConnector(share_cookies=True)
    response = yield from get(url, connector=connector)
    page = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response)
    # Do some stuff with page

urls = ['example.com/subdomain-A', 'example.com/subdomain-B', 'example.com/subdomain-C', ...]
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
tasks = [scraper(url) for url in urls]
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
```

As a matter of context, the pages I am trying to scrape are made in such a way that they test for the presence of a session cookie on loading, create one if none exists, then redirect to themselves. Now, with a simple minded scraping approach, I am stuck in a loop and with Asyncio/Aiohttp, nothing will happen.

Comment: At first you should use `TCPConnector`, not `BaseConnector`.

Next, use `asyncio.async` or `asyncio.Task` for running parallel tasks. I mean something like `asyncio.async(scrapper(url))`

Comment: I based my approach on the fact that there is about 30+ processes making network requests at the same time. In fact, only the actual network I/Os need to be asynchronous. That's why I use asyncio.wait instead. But thank you for the remark.
http://compiletoi.net/fast-scraping-in-python-with-asyncio.html